# C++ packages for graph processing

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, graph

I am working on a huge graph.
I'm interested to focus on a small part of the graph and make some optimization on it. 
All other "not interesting" nodes will be packed to one "supernode".

I am going to make number of iterations, each iteration will focus on another part of a graph. Then, I need to unpack existing supernode and pack another supernode.

I am looking for existing packages/algorithms which can do for me the packing/unpacking jobs.

I am working on C++ and using boost BGL.

Comment: Could you give an example of (un)packing, being that that's not a standard graph-theoretical term?

Comment: possibly it's overkill, but you might wish to shoot a glance at [leda](http://www.algorithmic-solutions.com/leda/).

Comment: the siple example  graph: 

    a->b->c->x->d->e

I am interested in x, so I will pack the graph : 

    abc->x->de

and unpacking in this case is to return supernode abce to its original graph: 

    a->b->c

*supernode abc